# How to use getFilter form Listadapter

Tags: java, android, listview, filter, adapter

I try to filter in Listview where the adapter is ListAdapter, I couldn't find getFilter() , Is there any work around? Below is my code.

```
// Adding menuItems to ListView
            final ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, songsListData,
                    R.layout.playlist_item, new String[]{"songTitle"}, new int[]{
                    R.id.songTitle});

            setListAdapter(adapter);

            sv.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
                    return false;
                }

                @Override
                public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
                    //adapter.getFilter
                    return false;
                }
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

I find myself, It's simple.

```
final SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, songsListData,
                    R.layout.playlist_item, new String[]{"songTitle"}, new int[]{
                    R.id.songTitle});

    sv.setOnQueryTextListener(new SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
                    return false;
                }

                @Override
                public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
                    adapter.getFilter().filter(newText);
                    return false;
                }
            });
```